# convert multi track+subtitles .MKV to MP4

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to tell Linux/Ubuntu to convert mkv file to mp4 file without any modification, i have many multi language+subtitles files in mkv i want to convert to mp4 but keeping all the same as the mkv file

actually I'm using this code

```
ffmpeg -i VIDEO.mkv -acodec copy  -vcodec copy -map 0:a VIDEO.mp4
```

but it's just saving the audio tracks, not video tracks

I tried different codes but none worked but this

EDIT: i tried with this Command

```
ffmpeg -i 13.Reasons.Why.S01E01.720p-www.DescargateloCorp.com.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy 13.Reasons.Why.S01E01.720p.mp4
```

i think it could work but i get this error message

> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument

```
> ffmpeg version N-75193-gf855353-Xtream-Codes Copyright (c) 2000-2015
> the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu
> 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)   configuration: --prefix=/root/FFmpeg/target --extra-cflags='-I/root/FFmpeg/target/include -static' --extra-ldflags='-L/root/FFmpeg/target/lib -lm -static' --extra-version=Xtream-Codes --disable-debug --disable-shared --enable-libx265 --enable-static --extra-cflags=--static --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-doc --enable-librtmp --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-libass --enable-gray --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-version3 --enable-libvpx --enable-libxavs --disable-devices --extra-libs='-lrtmp -lnettle -lhogweed -lgmp -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lc -ldl'   libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100   libavcodec     57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100   libavformat    57.  0.100 /
> 57.  0.100   libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100   libavfilter     6.  1.100 /  6.  1.100   libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100   libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100   libpostproc    54.  0.100 /
> 54.  0.100 Input #0, matroska,webm, from '13.Reasons.Why.S01E01.720p-www.DescargateloCorp.com.mkv':   Metadata:
>     title           : www.DescargateloCorp.com
>     encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
>     creation_time   : 2017-04-17 01:52:33   Duration: 00:52:57.65, start: 0.062000, bitrate: 1862 kb/s
>     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
>     Metadata:
>       title           : www.DescargateloCorp.com
>       BPS             : 1549034
>       BPS-eng         : 1549034
>       DURATION        : 00:52:38.280000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:52:38.280000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 75723
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 75723
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 611535569
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 611535569
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:1(spa): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Español Latino
>       BPS             : 160000
>       BPS-eng         : 160000
>       DURATION        : 00:52:57.632000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:52:57.632000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 99301
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 99301
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 63552640
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 63552640
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Ingles
>       BPS             : 160357
>       BPS-eng         : 160357
>       DURATION        : 00:52:57.621000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:52:57.621000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 148951
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 148951
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 63694551
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 63694551
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:3: Subtitle: subrip (default)
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Forzados
>       BPS             : 0
>       BPS-eng         : 0
>       DURATION        : 00:50:31.904000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:50:31.904000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 10
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 10
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 199
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 199
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:4(spa): Subtitle: subrip
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Español
>       BPS             : 57
>       BPS-eng         : 57
>       DURATION        : 00:49:59.496000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:49:59.496000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 772
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 772
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 21630
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 21630
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES [mp4 @ 0x530b120] Codec for stream 0 does not use
> global headers but container format requires global headers [mp4 @
> 0x530b120] Codec for stream 1 does not use global headers but
> container format requires global headers [mp4 @ 0x530b120] Codec for
> stream 2 does not use global headers but container format requires
> global headers [mp4 @ 0x530b120] Codec for stream 3 does not use
> global headers but container format requires global headers [mp4 @
> 0x530b120] Codec for stream 4 does not use global headers but
> container format requires global headers [mp4 @ 0x530b120] track 1:
> codec frame size is not set [mp4 @ 0x530b120] Could not find tag for
> codec subrip in stream #3, codec not currently supported in container
> Output #0, mp4, to '13.Reasons.Why.S01E01.720p.mp4':   Metadata:
>     title           : www.DescargateloCorp.com
>     encoder         : Lavf57.0.100
>     Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 16k tbn, 1k
> tbc (default)
>     Metadata:
>       title           : www.DescargateloCorp.com
>       BPS             : 1549034
>       BPS-eng         : 1549034
>       DURATION        : 00:52:38.280000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:52:38.280000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 75723
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 75723
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 611535569
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 611535569
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:1(spa): Audio: ac3 ([165][0][0][0] / 0x00A5), 48000 Hz, stereo, 160 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Español Latino
>       BPS             : 160000
>       BPS-eng         : 160000
>       DURATION        : 00:52:57.632000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:52:57.632000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 99301
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 99301
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 63552640
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 63552640
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Ingles
>       BPS             : 160357
>       BPS-eng         : 160357
>       DURATION        : 00:52:57.621000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:52:57.621000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 148951
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 148951
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 63694551
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 63694551
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:3: Subtitle: subrip (default)
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Forzados
>       BPS             : 0
>       BPS-eng         : 0
>       DURATION        : 00:50:31.904000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:50:31.904000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 10
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 10
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 199
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 199
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>     Stream #0:4(spa): Subtitle: subrip
>     Metadata:
>       title           : Español
>       BPS             : 57
>       BPS-eng         : 57
>       DURATION        : 00:49:59.496000000
>       DURATION-eng    : 00:49:59.496000000
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 772
>       NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 772
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 21630
>       NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 21630
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v7.0.0 ('Where We Going') 64bit built on Jun  9 2014 15:16:27
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-04-17 01:52:33
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
>       _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)   Stream
> #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)   Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)   Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)   Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

After digging arroung i found a solution using HandBreakCLI

1st. You need to install HandBreakCLI

then i used this code

```
HandBrakeCLI -i INPUT-MOVIE.mkv -o OUTPUT-MOVIE.mp4 -e x264 --all-audio --all-subtitles
```

With this HandBrake creates a new mp4 file, using H264, saving all audio and subtitles from the file with multiple stream/track audio or subtitles in it.

now i need to know how the hell i can make this command works for an entire directory.

Regards.

Comment: i guess you have it already, but to do it with your whole directory you can use this script in your console in the directory of your mkv files:  `for /F "tokens=*" %G in ('dir /b *.mkv') do HandBrakeCLI -i "%G" -o "%~nG.mp4" -e x264 --all-audio --all-subtitles`